# How to get monaco editor instance inside VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know that due to [VS Code architecture](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1970) its not possible to access monaco editor instance inside extensions.
But using [mockney patching](https://github.com/iocave/monkey-patch) I was able to inject my custom code inside main UI thread. So how I can access monaco editor instance?

my sample code that runs inside main UI thread

```js
define([
    "module",
    "require",
    "vs/platform/instantiation/common/instantiationService",
    "vs/base/common/platform",
    


], function (module, require, insantiationService, platform) {
        'use strict';
        console.log('');
        console.log(platform)        
    });
```

Comment: So did you figure it out?